# Client/Server Programming

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am practicing a simple java program where I am demonstrating simple client server interaction. The fist part of message from server gets transferred. Then program just continues to run and does not execute? Do we need to create a new socket for each individual traffic?

Server code

```
server = new ServerSocket(4587);
System.out.print("Starting the Server on port " + server.getLocalPort() + "\n");
System.out.println("Waiting for client...");

Socket client = server.accept();
BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
br.write("Hello, you are connected to Server. What is your name?");
br.write("\n");
br.flush();



while((s=br1.readLine())!=null)
    {

    }
     br.write("Thank you ");
     br.newLine();
    br.flush();
    }
```

Client code

```
String stdin;
System.out.println("Attempting to connect to " + hostname + ":" + port);
client = new Socket("localhost", 4587);
System.out.println("Connection Established");

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
while ((stdin = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(stdin);
}

BufferedWriter br1 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
br1.write("Mike");
br1.write("\n");
br1.flush();

while ((stdin = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(stdin);
}
```

Server Output

```
Starting the Server on port4587
Waiting for client....
```

Client Output

```
 Attempting to connect to :123
 Connection Established
 Hello you are connected to Server, What is ur name
```

If this could help..after this both loop

Comment: Why the down vote? He has shown effort.

Comment: Well, IMHO, the the problem is reported in a vague way, and there is no clear reference to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server will first create a connection with the client through the `accept` method. If you wish to have multiple clients you will need to change your code accordingly to accept that.

On the client side, you're using `\n` to delineate the end of a message. This will work fine. Every time you send a new message use `\n` to indicate the end of the message.

On the server side, you should continue reading from I/O until you see the `\n`. At that point you have received the entire message. Process it and than start listening again.

**Edit:**

Since you are waiting for the name of the client, you could simply do the following on the server:

```
BufferedWriter bout = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamWriter(client.getInputStream()));
// Wait for incoming name from client.
String name = bin.readline();
System.out.println(name);
// Send a reply.
bout.write("Thank you\n");
bout.flush();
```

Similarly, on the client (assuming `bin` and `bout` are defined the same as above):

```
// Send name to server.
bout.write("Name\n");
bout.flush();
// Get a response from the server and print to console.
String response = bin.readline();
System.out.println(response);
```

Comment: That would be acceptable - it really just depends on what you're trying to achieve. Inside your `while` loop you can read each message and process it. After your done you'll go back to reading the next line. You may want to consider listening forever (in a `while(true)` loop) on a separate thread to allow the server to do other things besides listening all the time.

Comment: @Koneri I've updated my answer. Hopefully it will get you started.

Comment: Fine this solves it thank you. And i had one question one connection is set up between client and server. Can we call the method of server and receive the response.

Comment: @Koneri If my answer solved your problem, don't forget to select it as the answer for the question (check mark next to my answer). As for your question, I'm not sure I understand. The `Socket client = server.accept();` binds the server to the client (creating a connection). That method blocks (doesn't execute past the line) until a client connects successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This is because BufferedReader has a default buffer = 8K when in reading process and this process is block I/O, so this will hang in that point. You should read the full message from client by server side.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the loop on the client side. It will be stuck in the loop as it **waits to readlines sent from the server infinitely**. (ie, after reading the first line from the server, it will expect more lines from the server and wait to read them).

To exit the loop you need to send an EOF signal or end of stream signal (according to the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29)

Comment: He's sending a `\n` which is his indicator for EOF.